# How to model the vacuum-solid interface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

Consider an ordinary object, e.g. metal or an insulator placed in a simulation mesh to simulate a CFD physics problem, creating a solid-vacuum interface. I cannot model this as a dense ideal gas as it would expand feely. I am simulating the dynamics of another fluid whose behavior is being impacted by this diffusion on the time-scale of interest.

Hence, What are some methods to simulate the interface without introducing any interface diffusion ?

Comment: So do you have a [multiphase flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphase_flow)? Or is it just a solid boundary that you could apply?

Comment: At the interface between a solid and vacuum, the traction vector at the interface is zero (provided it is perfect vacuum).  Is this what you were looking for?  Or do you have a non-perfect vacuum and diffusion of a solvent within the soil toward the interface (and you are looking for a mass transfer condition?